# Is Kubernetes' ETCD exposed for us to use?

Tags: kubernetes

We are working on provisioning our service using Kubernetes and the service needs to register/unregister some data for scaling purposes. Let's say the service handles long-held transactions so when it starts/scales out, it needs to store the starting and ending transaction ids somewhere. When it scales out further, it will need to find the next transaction id and save it with the ending transaction id that is covered. When it scales in, it needs to delete the transaction ids, etc. ETCD seems to make the cut as it is used (by Kubernetes) to store deployment data and not only that it is close to Kubernetes, it is actually inside and maintained by Kubernetes; thus we'd like to find out if that is open for our use. I'd like to ask the question for both EKS, AKS, and self-installed. Any advice welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Do *not*** use the kubernetes etcd directly for an application.

Access to read/write data to the kubernetes etcd store is **root** access to every node in your cluster. Even if you are well versed in etcd v3's [role based security](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.3.12/op-guide/authentication/) model avoid sharing that specific etcd instance so you don't increase your clusters attack surface.

For EKS and GKE, the etcd cluster is hidden in the provided cluster service so you can't break things. I would assume AKS takes a similar approach unless they expose the instances to you that run the management nodes.

If the data is small and not heavily updated, you might be able to reuse the kubernetes etcd store via the kubernetes API. Create a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#should-i-use-a-configmap-or-a-custom-resource) or a [custom resource definition](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) for your data and edit it via the easily securable and namespaced functionality in the kubernetes API.

For most application uses run your own etcd cluster (or whatever service) to keep Kubernetes free to do it's workload scheduling. The [coreos etcd operator](https://github.com/coreos/etcd-operator/blob/master/README.md) will let you define and create new etcd clusters easily.